# Best datastructure for matrix with lot of mutation

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, data-structures, graph

I have difficulties thinking of an efficient `data structure` to save matrices (they can be close to 75x75 in size). 1's are the only important cells the 0's will always be empty and are useless. Also I would prefer if we could just not load the 0's into the `data structure`.

---

```
        Col 1   Col 2  Col 3 Col 4  Col 5
Row 1       0       0      1     0      1
Row 2       0       1      0     0      0
Row 3       1       1      0     0      0
Row 4       0       0      0     0      0
Row 5       0       0      1     0      1
```

Please keep in mind I will be making an algorithm to sort this `matrix` where I will be moving a lot of column and rows.

I was thinking of a table with row, column and value. But am not sure if this is the best option. My teacher told me to look at a `graph structure`; it looked promising for saving the data but moving the rows and columns looked like hell to me.

Any suggestions on `data structures` that would fit this purpose ?

Comment: Perhaps this is useful for you:
https://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/

Comment: @heaphach first line from your link - _is a linear algebra library for manipulating **dense** matrices_. Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 4):

For a sparse array, a `HashMap` is an excellent choice. It's relatively fast - `O(1)` lookup - and relatively space efficient. I say relatively because there are many overheads.

There are other `Map` implementations that have different behaviour - for example a `TreeMap` performs in `O(lg n)` but is sorted by key.

So whilst a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>` or some such, might well save you space with a `100x100` very sparse matrix, I would imagine that an `int[][]` won't be much less efficient.

If performance is a concern, you should definitely benchmark the alternatives using something like [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). I would expect the `int[][]` to outperform a `Map` based solution in most circumstances.

If you are using Guava, you could use a [`Table`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained). The two alternatives I describe above are essentially the [`HashBasedTable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html) and the [`ArrayTable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html). I wouldn't expect the `ArrayTable` to be much slower than a raw `int[][]`, but it will take more space.

In short:

1. Benchmark
2. Benchmark
3. Benchmark

Comment: I think you should clarify that you mean HashMaps. There are other Maps with different runtime behaviour. Btw HashMaps can be initialized with a size to optimize space usage.

Comment: @LastFreeNickname done. To optimise space you would need to set the size **and** and load factor. This wouldn't solve the speed issues - it is likely to be slower than array access. But the OP needs to benchmark to see if the speed difference outweighs the memory difference.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thank you very much for the benchmark library i just setup an project to be able to benchmark any possible solutions thanks !